# Problem with $ (1+\frac1n)^{n}$

Tags: limits, natural-numbers

I've noticed that if I consider $(1+\frac1n)^{n}$ and calculate its value when $n=10^3$ or $n=10^4$ I obtain a real number that is really close to $e$ but when I calculate it when $n=10^{11}$ or $n=10^{12}$ then I obtain $1$. I think it happens because for $n=10^{11}$ the  part $(1+\frac1n)$ is approximately $1$ then $1^n$ is $1$. But I also know that $\lim_{n\to+\infty}(1+\frac1n)^{n}=e$ so why for some value of $n$ I obtain $1$? Is it contradicting the limit? Thank you advance!!

Comment: I take it's a problem in accuracy of the calculator. In the sense that it will consider $0.1^{11}$ to be $0$ and hence $1+1/10^11$ is $1$ as far as the calculator is concerned.

Comment: Machine accuracy problem, I suppose. How are you computing the values ?

Comment: Just substitute the value of $n$ in the sequence using a normal calculator

Comment: In short, you are right.  The machine approximates $1+\frac{1}{10^11}$ as 1.  More difficult cases of this are a constant, serious problem in high precision numerical methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably pa precision thing. Computers do not have infinite space and can therefore represent only a finite set of numbers exactly. Any operation you do on the numbers which results in a number that the computer cannot represent will result in rounding.

This means that there exists some *smallest number* which is still greater than $1$ and is still representable by the computer, and if the result of $1+\frac1n$ is close enough to $1$, the computer will make an estimation that $1+\frac1n = 1$, therefore, $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n = 1^n=1.$

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your calculator or computer, not the mathematical limit. Because of the way floating point numbers work, they store a limited amount digits as well as the power. So even though $1\times 10^{-11}$ is valid, you can't store the number $1+10^{-11}$ accurately, since this would require too many digits of precision. Instead, the computer just rounds this number down to $1$, and you get your result.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the sequence $( 1 + \frac{1}{n})^{n}$ is an increasing sequence, which is bounded above by $e$, and $e$ is in fact the least upper bound for the sequence, hence is the limit.
The answer is that there is a fault in the computer's accuracy, there is no counterexample to the theory. If the computer contradicts the theory, then you can be sure that the fault is with the computer.

Comment: That does not answer OPs question. At all.

Comment: @5xum :OK, I've said a little more.